# Animations missing from android.R.anim?

Tags: android, animation, sdk

I'm beginning with android development and am a bit confused about the available animation types in `android.R.anim`.

The `android.R.anim` class only has 13 members:

```
public static final int accelerate_decelerate_interpolator = 17432580;
public static final int accelerate_interpolator = 17432581;
public static final int anticipate_interpolator = 17432583;
public static final int anticipate_overshoot_interpolator = 17432585;
public static final int bounce_interpolator = 17432586;
public static final int cycle_interpolator = 17432588;
public static final int decelerate_interpolator = 17432582;
public static final int fade_in = 17432576;
public static final int fade_out = 17432577;
public static final int linear_interpolator = 17432587;
public static final int overshoot_interpolator = 17432584;
public static final int slide_in_left = 17432578;
public static final int slide_out_right = 17432579;
```

Yet the res/anim folder in android.jar contains 74 animation definition xml files.

How can I access those "missing" animation types?

I already tried cleaning / rebuilding the project.

I'm using:

- SDK platform 2.3.3 (API level 10)
- IntelliJ IDEA 11 Ultimate

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I access those "missing" animation types?

Copy them from the SDK into your project.

Comment: Sure, I could do that, but that can hardly be the "correct" way?!

Comment: @UloPe: You act as though you have a choice.

Comment: Well that is really the core of my question. Why are those files in the SDK but not in the corresponding R.anim class?

Comment: @UloPe: Because they are not part of the SDK, per se. Just as there are classes and methods in Android's Java framework that are not part of the SDK, there are resources in Android that are not part of the SDK. As to why they ship them via the SDK instead of just having you obtain them from the open source project, I cannot say.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean and rebuild your entire project.